# I have to Find all possible values of $\sqrt{|x|-2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have to Find all possible values of $\sqrt{|x|-2}$

Now this is defined for $|x| \geq 2$. but how do i find range corresponding to this domain?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

The range is all $0\leq y$. Given $0\leq y$, choose $x=y^2+2$. Note that $2\leq|x|$ and 
$$
\sqrt{|x|-2}=\sqrt{|y^2+2|-2}=\sqrt{y^2+2-2}=\sqrt{y^2}=|y|=y
$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

- What are all the possible values of $\sqrt{x}$?
- If I give you a value of $x_0$, can you find some $x$ such that $\sqrt{x_0} = \sqrt{|x|-2}$?

Comment: 1. $x \geq 0$...

Comment: @J.Deff Correct. Now, say I pick $x_0=4$. Can you find some $x$ such that $\sqrt{|x|-2}=\sqrt{4}$? How about if I pick $x_0=9$? What about if $x_0=5$?

Comment: 1.$x=\pm 6$..others are similar

Comment: @J.Deff Then you know all you need to know to answer the question.

Comment: cannot get this

Comment: What is the problem in following. $|x| \geq 0$ . $|x|-2 \geq -2$. How do i get square root in here?

Comment: @J.Deff You know that $\sqrt{x}$ takes every non-negative value. And you know that for any value that $\sqrt{x}$ takes, $\sqrt{|x|-2}$ also takes that value (for some other $x$, but still). Therefore...

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\sqrt{0}=0$$

$$\lim_{x -\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt{x}=\infty$$

This is a continuous function.

Answer (score 0):

Why not look at the graph of your function? It is not necessary but you can "see" in this graph the answer (the quotes are because of the easy limit involved).

[image]